# Screen of nested Conductor not being activated

Tags: c#, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a `ShellViewModel` which inherits from `Conductor<Workspace>.Collection.OneActive` and a `ShellView` which has a `ContenControl` with a `x:Name` attribute of `ActiveItem`.

*Note that `Workspace` inherits `Screen`.*

**ShellViewModel**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<Workspace>.Collection.OneActive
{
    ShellViewModel(IEnumerable<Workspace> items)
    {
        this.Items = items;
        // below is not how I activate, just an example for descriptive purposes
        this.ActivateItem(this.Items.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == "Container"));
    }
}
```

**ShellView**

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
```

In the above, my `Items` collection is successfully populated with objects of `Workspace` and the `object of Workspace` is successfully shown in the `ContentControl` when `ActivateItem` is called.

The `ActiveItem` is a `Screen` and not a `Conductor<Workspace>` which it contains an `ObservableCollection<PanelViewModel>`.  My `ContainerView` has an `ItemsControl` with its `ItemsSource` bound to the `PanelViewCollection` and its template override to display using a `UniformGrid.

**ContainerViewModel**

```
public class ContainerViewModel : Screen
{
    // get/set implantation missed for brevity
    public ObservableCollection<PanelViewModel> PanelViewCollection
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void AddPanelViewModel()
    {
        var @new = new PanelViewModel();
        this.PanelViewCollection.Add(@new);
    }
}
```

**ContainerView**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PanelViewCollection}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <UniformGrid/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

A `Button` on my `ContainerView` calls the `AddPanelViewModel` function on the `ContainerViewModel` and a `new PanelViewModel` is added to the collection and it becomes visible on the `ContainerView`.

Up to this point everything appears to be working OK.

The `PanelViewModel` inherits from `Conductor<Workspace>.Collection.OneActive` and the `PanelView` has a `ContenControl` with a `x:Name` attribute of `ActiveItem.

**PanelViewModel**

```
public class PanelViewModel : Conductor<Workspace>.Collection.OneActive
{
    PanelViewModel(IEnumerable<Workspace> items)
    {
        this.Items = items;
        // below is not how I activate, just an example for descriptive purposes
        this.ActivateItem(this.Items.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == "PanelA"));
    }
}
```

**PanelView**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="There be treasure here!" />
    <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
</StackPanel>
```

Whilst the `PanelView` is displayed (I see treasure here) the `ActiveItem` is not being shown and I think it has something to do with activation, as the `OnActivate` method of the `Workspace` being activated is not being called.

What have I missed?

**Edit**

I have committed an example to a [Git repo](https://github.com/unflux/Caliburn.Micro.NestedConductor/tree/dev/Caliburn.Micro.NestedConductor) for those who my be inclined to review it:

Comment: How are checking that the OnActivate method of the Workspace is not called? have you overridden OnActivate? It might also be worth debugging the `PanelViewModel` to see what the activated state is.

Comment: @Chris - Yeah I put an `override OnActivate` method in the `Workspaces` to see if they were being called. I have also just committed example code to a Git repo (link in post) if you have any time to review.  I have omitted all non essential code.  It does appear that the `PanelViewModel` is not active, `IsActive=false`, is that the/an issue?

Comment: I think that may be the problem, great example by the way! I have to run, but I'll try and take a deeper look when I get some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further reading I believe there were two issues with my implementation described in the OP.

1. My `ContainerView` `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` `DataTemplate` was incorrect.  I appeared to be displaying the `View` rather than the `ViewModel`.
2. As my `ContainerView` was partially managing `Screen` lifetimes, it should have been inheriting from `Conductor` which it was not.

I have committed a working implementation to the [Git repo](https://github.com/unflux/Caliburn.Micro.NestedConductor) for anyone that may come across the same or a similar issue.

Comment: @Chris - Thanks, and thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I found that if you happen to have the following hierarchy: AScreen \ AConductor \ ASubConductor, where AScreen shows AConductor through a `ContentControl` just setting some bound public property, it happens that **ASubConductor** will not get activated (even if AConductor activates that). To work properly, it is not enough to set AConductor to the property: AScreen must also *manually* activate it. HTH